# Bootstrap table and Bootstrap 4 support

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I use Bootstrap table, namely this solution: 
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table

It does not appear to support Bootstrap 4. Consequently, the table layout is a bit funky, as per this screenshot:
[image]

I think this is a great package, but the lack of Bootstrap 4 support is a problem. Is there a competing package that is recommended for a new solution?

Comment: Datatables would probably be best for this project

Comment: Not sure I understand. This package (bootstrap-table) is to format HTML tables/grids, so nothing to do with databases.

Comment: he said datatables not databases

Comment: Gotcha!! Yes, I mis-read that, took a look at DataTables, and it looks alright. I spent time moving some functionality across and so far it looks like a fit.

Answer (score 0):

Per Mattigins, I am testing DataTables as an alternative. Thanks!